# PadRight when consider crlf is not working well

Tags: c#, text-alignment

I want to print many line. Each line is a string plus white spaces plus a second string.

I want the second part string in each line aligning. So I use PadRight; but it is not working well.

Code:

```
void Main()
{
   var str ="Hellooooo".PadRight(50)+"Test";
   str += (Environment.NewLine+"World").PadRight(50)+"Test";
   str+= (Environment.NewLine+"Hello Worldoooooooo").PadRight(50)+"Test";
   Console.WriteLine(str);
}
```

The output likes
[image: 1]

You can see the three "Test" are not aligning vertically.

Comment: Usually its better to use a more table friendly control. Does it really need to be aligned using whitespaces? If it is not Console's output. The screenshot looks different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you like to align text white spaces, then you need a [mono space font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font) (every char same width), like courier new.

Also `Environment.NewLine` is in the second and third string, but not the first.

When fixing the `Environment.NewLine` and using a monospace font, this works:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var str ="Hellooooo".PadRight(50)+"Test";
    str += Environment.NewLine + ("World").PadRight(50)+"Test";
    str += Environment.NewLine + ("Hello Worldoooooooo").PadRight(50)+"Test";
    Console.WriteLine(str);
}
```

[image: result]

See [live demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1hTe4w)

Comment: No, I changed all letters as 'o'. Same result. I test it by LinqPad.

Comment: So how can I align them? The string is generated at run time.

Comment: What's the output? File? Console? Webpage?

Comment: It is radgridview

Comment: Like @Julian said, you need to use a fixed-width font. I like CONSOLAS.

Comment: I am not sure dotnetfiddle demo is right. I can't get your result in LinqPad. Actually, `Environment.NewLine` has two chars. Can you test it in LinqPad?@Julian

Comment: LinqPad isnt using a mono space output: http://forum.linqpad.net/discussion/1150/how-do-i-get-monospaced-results